# gnome under Ubuntu 18.04 for Windows won't run

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

After installing Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 I can not get gnome
to start. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu with same results. See below:

```
$ sudo gnome-session
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gnome-session-check-accelerated:2226): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:51.687: cannot open display: :0.0
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
(gnome-session-check-accelerated:2227): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:17:52.949: cannot open display: :0.0
gnome-session-binary[2217]: WARNING: software acceleration check failed: Child process exited with code 1
gnome-session-binary[2217]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
ken@DESKTOP-64ED1AI:~$
```

Comment: One doesn't normally run gnome-session as root. Also you are supposed to start it from your .xsession or similar. Having said that, gnome seems to have problems starting in non standard ways (e.g. some vnc setups, xrdp etc).

Answer (score 3):

Windows Subsystem for Linux is [not designed to provide a GUI](https://askubuntu.com/a/1119944/197910). However, with [WSL2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-install), brave Penguinistas have pushed back the Frontiers of Computer Science and [found](https://askubuntu.com/a/1154366/197910) [ways](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/bcrud9/wsl_distro_manager_for_windows_10_19h1/). [Complex ways](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/cvqqs4/guiapps_on_wsl2/).

However, the preferred method to run Ubuntu underneath Windows is virtualization, such as is available free with [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and other virtual machines.

Other folks, laboring in their digital vineyards of knowledge, have found `rm -rf /` [works too](https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/rmrf-in-wsl.html).

Comment: Not a great example there... Try using `xfce`. Seems to work well for a lot of us. Using it combined with X410 and you have a great experience.